# Should subset question be closed as duplicates?

Tags: discussion

Consider these 2 questions;

[Does Islam allow to keep any pets that aren't dogs but are still part of the dog family?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1508/does-islam-allow-to-keep-any-pets-related-to-the-dog-family)

[What kind of pets can I keep in my house?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/610/what-kind-of-pets-can-i-keep-in-my-house)

First question is a subset of second question. Answer the second question should be enough to answer first question. They cover the same ground in some sense. On the other hand, there are not 100% dupe. What should we do about these kinds of questions?

Comment: obligatory blog link: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Answer (score 2):

As goldPseudo pointed out, a large amount of duplication is bad, and a single, canonical answer that handles every variation is unlikely. So subtle variation and some duplication is okay.

In this case, I think it's clear from chat that subset questions are okay. The question about pets addresses cats and birds specifically, and the question about dogs addresses dogs specifically. They don't even overlap much in answers.

Looks good to me.